# How to let the user change style elements of a form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I've to build a web-based tool which lets an user change the CSS style of form elements.

E.g. a form contains of two labels, two text fields and a button. The user should now (somehow) be able to set styles like `color:red`, `border:1px` or `text-align:right` (or in any other way define such stuff). This settings should be check (if valid or not) and saved.

In any circumstance it shouldn't be possible to perform an injection attack or to destroy or change (e.g. by removing a text field) the form.

Right now, I'm just seeking for some ideas of how I could handle this request or if there are some useful libraries (PHP, JS, ...). So if anyone want to share his mind if me, I'm more than glad.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the best place for brainstorming... That said, I think it would be best to provide a more structured way of entering the values (like a form) rather than allowing free-style CSS.

Comment: I already thought about it, but the problem starts if the actual form gets bigger and more complex - like containing a lot of different elements (radio, drop-down, ...) and it maybe also should be possible to adjust the style of a table around it...

Comment: Problem with allowing too much customization is it tends to confuse users. So I would generally allow them to customize only the things that have the most impact. On the other hand, if you insist on having a very customizable experience, you can organize different properties into tabs. Take a look at the Blogger.com's template designer for a good example.

Answer (score 0):

This link may be of help http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0412697

This page makes use of style switcher and the Bootstrap plugin, which changes the colour of the page according to what you select, referring to the code of this 'style switcher' may be the resolution to your problem.